# ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file

Tags: java, spring

My spring application compiled with java 1.8 in local system where it's working fine without any issues, but when I deploy the application on the server where java-11 configured, giving an error message in server start-up

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: 
Failed to read candidate component class: URL
[jar:file:/app/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/webapps/planDeTravail/WEB-INF/lib/rna-1.20.jar!/com/DoRnaHistory.class]; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file -
 probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [java/io/Serializable.class]; 
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/rna-spring-context.xml]; nested exception
 is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably
 due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [java/io/Serializable.class]; 
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68
```

My spring application running in 3.2.16.RELEASE
Could anyone please help me to find the root cause and solution of the issue?

Comment: Spring 3.2.16 support Java only up to version 1.8. For Java 11 support you need to update your spring version to 5.1 at least (https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/21/spring-framework-5-1-goes-ga: "specifically supports JDK 11"). If you must stay on Spring 3.2.16 your server must run the application with Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I changed my JRE version back to 8 when using         `<org.springframework.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>`
In Intellij i also changed the app configuration to run with JRE 8.